# How to access dynamic arrays in struct with ctypes?

Tags: ctypes

This is my minimal example code.

```py
import ctypes as c
import numpy as np
import subprocess

## the c code
c_code = """
```

```c
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct My_Struct_{
    int n;
    float *b;

}My_Struct;

My_Struct *my_struct_new(int n) {
    My_Struct *result = malloc(sizeof *result);
    result->n = n;
    result->b = malloc(n*sizeof result->b[0]);
    memset(result->b,1.0,n*sizeof result->b[0]);
    return result;
}
```

```c
"""
## creating the so file
with open('temp.c', 'w') as f:
    f.write(c_code)
cmmd = "gcc -std=c99 -lm -shared -o temp.so -fPIC temp.c -lm -Wall -pedantic"
print subprocess.call(cmmd, shell=True)

## importing the so file
c_foo=c.cdll.LoadLibrary("./temp.so")
n = 5

class My_Struct(c.Structure):
 _fields_= [("n",c.c_int),
            ("b",c.POINTER(c.c_float*n))]
my_struct_new = c_foo.my_struct_new
my_struct_new.argtype = [c.c_int]
my_struct_new.restype = c.POINTER(My_Struct)

## creating the struct
p_my_struct = my_struct_new(n)

# trying to read from the struct
print p_my_struct.contents.b[0]
print np.ctypeslib.as_array(p_my_struct.contents.b, (n,1))
```

But instead of the expected

```
[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
```

I get:

```
<__main__.c_float_Array_5 object at 0x35fe3b0>
[[]
 [�@�^]
 [��A��������]
 [`��J�]
 [t*Op]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed a pointer instead of the array. It should be `as_array(p_my_struct[0].b[0], (n, 1))`.

Comments:

- You have a typo. It should be `argtypes` with an s.
- `memset` sets a `char` value, so each value will be `c_float.from_buffer(bytearray('\1\1\1\1')) == 2.3694278276172396e-38`.
- If you want the values as a Python `list`, use `p_my_struct[0].b[0][:]`.